# Rails Carrierwave Multiple Images with mount_uploaders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I am using the master branch of *Carrierwave* and using the mount_uploaders method. I can use the *mount_uploader* method and upload individual images, just not when using multiple.

I am receiving this message and can't narrow down what the problem is exactly.

After saving, on both Create and Update I receive:

**NoMethodError**

```
undefined method `map' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd281d6cdc8>
```

**Parameter Request:**

```
"award_images"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd281d6cdc8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/zx/47b5lzf16312zkh6949lm1_80000gq/T/RackMultipart20150210-22178-x4x4h9>,
 @original_filename="2009_01_addy_cfgc_videos.jpg",
```

**Using json column -** award_images:json

**View: _form**

```
<h2>Featured Image</h2>
<p>
     <%= image_tag(@award.award_images_url, :class => "image img-responsive featured") if @award.award_images? %> 
    <%= f.file_field :award_images, multiple: true, name: "award[award_images]" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :award_images_cache %>
    </p>

    <p>
<label>
  <%= f.check_box :remove_award_images %>
  Remove Images
</label>
    </p>
```

**Model:**

```
class Award < ActiveRecord::Base
mount_uploaders :award_images, AwardImageUploader
end
```

**Controller:** My strong params

```
private

def award_params
params.require(:award).permit(:title, :award_images, :etc)
end
```

**Extra Details:**

Rails 4.1.8

Ruby 2.1.2

Postgres

Answer (score 1):

Official whitelisting of params is slightly different. The multiple uploads should be whitelisted as `{variables: []}`. Try the following:

```
def award_params
   params.require(:award).permit(:title, {award_images: []}, :etc)
end
```

[source](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/carrierwave/frames#Multiple_file_uploads)

Answer (score 0):

In your view file try different name:

```
<%= f.file_field :award_images, multiple: true, name: "award[award_images][]" %>
```

The brackets indicate that the input field is an array (more than one image).

Comment: Bleh, didn't work. I have now tried to also use a Postgres array column. Which also isn't working. I no longer get an error though. So I'm going to try working this array method and will post updates. Otherwise, looks like I'll have to do it the long way. Thanks!

Comment: @nil did you ever end up figuring it out? I'm currently in the same position. Not trying to do associations, like you.